# Could you help me understand the following code :

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, arguments

is *argv[1] a way to go over all elements of an array

```
#include <unistd.h>

int     main(char **argv)
{

    while (*argv[1])
    {
        if (*argv[1] == 'a')
        {
            write(1, "a", 1);
            break;
        }
        argv[1]++;
    }
}
```

what about argv[1]++ : is it to add one to the address

Comment: `int main(char **argv)` isn't a valid form for `main`. Did you want `int main(int argc, char **argv)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant the standard:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

`argv[1]` is a pointer to the first command line argument to the program. `*argv[1]` is then the first character of the argument, the same as `argv[1][0]`.

Incrementing `argv[1]` makes it point to the next character of that argument.

The `while (*argv[1])` test will fail when it gets to the null terminator of the string.

So this code is looping over the characters in the first argument, and printing `a` whenever finds an `a` character in the argument.  If you run:

```
./a.out aardvark
```

it will print

```
aaa
```